# Why am I getting ( WooCommerce Services could not be installed (Could not create directory.). ) error and how to solve it ?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

`PayPal by Braintree could not be installed (Could not create directory.). Please install it manually by clicking here.`

`WooCommerce Services could not be installed (Could not create directory.). Please install it manually by clicking here.`

I'm getting those two errors and I don't know how to solve them??

please help

thank you .

Comment: it could be a permissions problem .

Comment: I'm not sure but `sudo chown www-data:www-data wp-content -R` could solve it